# How to include the Oracle user in expdp?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, datapump

I have been trying various options and different user accounts to run the expdp so it can include the user/schema information so when I run the impdp commmand, it will re-create the user if it doesn't exist.  I can't get this work. I have tried with a user (member of dba role) and also tried with "as sysdba" account when running the expdp command.  I can see from the log, the USER metadata is not exported.  Hence when I attempted to run the impdp, it threw an error about the "user does not exist".   What do I need to do to get this to work?

**====== Log =======**

```
C:\>expdp schemas=myschema directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=expdp_myschema.dmp l
ogfile=expdp_myschema.log

Export: Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on Tue Aug 2 11:54:05 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Username: / as sysdba

Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit
Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing opt
ions

WARNING: Oracle Data Pump operations are not typically needed when connected to
the root or seed of a container database.

Starting "SYS"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01":  /******** AS SYSDBA schemas=myschema dir
ectory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=expdp_myschema.dmp logfile=expdp_myschema.log
Estimate in progress using BLOCKS method...
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
Total estimation using BLOCKS method: 64 KB
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/DEFAULT_ROLE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PRE_SCHEMA/PROCACT_SCHEMA
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/STATISTICS/MARKER
. . exported "MYSCHEMA"."PRODUCT"                        5.507 KB       1 rows
Master table "SYS"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
******************************************************************************
Dump file set for SYS.SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01 is:
  C:\APP\ORACLE\ADMIN\ORADEV\DPDUMP\EXPDP_MYSCHEMA.DMP
Job "SYS"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01" successfully completed at Tue Aug 2 11:54:18 20
16 elapsed 0 00:00:09
```

Comment: What are you actually running? Are you exporting a few tables? A schema? The database?

Comment: Trying to export a schema.

Comment: What is the actual `expdp` command you are running though - it would help to show the whole command with all its arguments (hiding anything sensitive of course). Are you running it as a user with the `EXP_FULL_DATABASE` privilege?

Comment: I not able to paste the entire log because space limited here.  Here's the command and when it prompts for credential, I entere "/ as sysdba".             expdp schemas=myschema directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=expdp_myschema.dmp logfile=expdp_myschema.log

Comment: OK, I attached log in my original message.

Comment: Are you importing as SYS too, and also under 12c? Have you tried setting your ORACLE_SID to your PDB instead of the CDB? You can also run `impdp` with the `sqlfile` option to see what it would try to create.

Comment: I am not sure what you meant by "importing as SYS too".  The expdp command I ran is the command I frequently find in examples posted on the web.  So I am just following it along.  I even tried with a user who is a member of the dba role.  That didn't work either.  So I am just running out of ideas.  Do you have an example of where you talked about setting the ORACLE_SID to PDB?